# Less::ParseError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined - Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, less

> **Note:** ruby 2.0.0p481, Rails 4.0.13

**Execute :** `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

**Trace:**

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails < 4.1.0 will be dropped.
>   (called from  at
>   /host_share/project/config/application.rb:9) rake aborted!
>   Less::ParseError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined   (in
>   /host_share/project/app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.less) at
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:604:31
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/parser.rb:100:in
>   `block in to_css'

I dont know whats wrong ... please help me..

Comment: There is a problem in your `/stylesheets/main.css.less`. Can you post this css file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear here: In your `app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.less` you are doing a `.split()` operation on an undefined object, hence this is raising an error. Go in that file, search for the `.split()` method and check why the object you are calling this method on is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.less` search for `split`. Remove `split` from the file and inspect the object you're calling split on to see if it's not `nill`